# Reading Exchange 2003 WebDAV custom properties with EWS after upgrading to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, webdav

I have an old Exchange 2003 server that we connected to via WebDAV. We had one app using it and in it we were setting some custom properties to appointments in the DAV namespace like `DAV:OrderId`, where OrderId is the name of the custom property.

Now we're going to move the mailbox to Exchange 2010 to start with and since there's no WebDAV support for it, I can't find a way how to read that custom property with Managed EWS (Exchange Web Services).
I tried getting them with searching through
`DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common`
and
`DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings`
collections, but of course they're not there.
Our app kind of needs those properties to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you look at one item where you know the property is set with a Mapi editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi this allows you to see all properties available on the item. You should be able to view the property definition then and use that to work out what your extended property definition should be (if its there at all)

Comment: I tried MFCMapi. It's not even show there. Shows absolutely nothing in it. I'll try OutlookSpy. But I know it's on the item, because I can get it back via WebDAV in 2003

Comment: well i tried it again on the Exchange 2003 and I've found the custom props with all their info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found what I was doing wrong.
By using MFCMapi on the Exchange 2003 server I was able to see that the actual full property name is `"DAV:OrderId"` and not just `"OrderId"`. It's namespace is `DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings`. So just use those two pieces of information when querying with EWS and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't be more specific here, but I've not wanted to grab any custom properties off Exchange items.  However, there is a way to get MAPI props in EWS, and there may be a way to dig out the custom props as well.  It's worth a look.  Start [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/36ceb734-a221-4dc9-b996-866e538b0f59/getting-to-mapi-properties-via-ews-managed-api?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment), and let us know if you work it out!